# GCP Storage API read Limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rate-limiting

I tried to find everywhere if there is a rate-limit for read requests to the Storage API, but didn't manage to find any info. Any idea where could it be?
I would like to see information regarding rate-limit per serviceAccount/project/session or anything of that sort.

Comment: If you didn't find it's because it does not exist!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere what do you mean? You can do as many requests as possible and there won't be any throttling?

Comment: Yes, that is. Cloud Storage also cache elements to speed up and reduce the number of call to the core infrastructure.